# Linq: create a query that returns a subtype object populated with parent type object values

Tags: c#, linq

In I have a class defined as follows:

```
class Person
{
    string FirstName;
    string LastName;
    /* ... */
}

class Student
{
    Person Person;
    int SomeWeirdData;
    /* ... */
}
```

... a list:

```
List<Person> People;
```

...and this query:

```
var q = from p in People select new Student() { Person = p, SomeWeirdData = 0 };
```

I would like to "flatten" Student this way:

```
class Student : Person
{
    int SomeWeirdData;
}
```

and I wonder what's the best way to rebuild my query. Of course I could do:

```
var q = from p in people select new Student() { FirstName = p.FirstName, LastName = p.LastName, /* all other Person properties, */ SomeWeirdData = 0 };
```

but I hope there is a way to create `Student` from `Person`, adding extra fields only, like:

```
/* pseudo-code */
var q = from p in people select p as Student with { SomeWeirdData = 0 };
```

The goal is to avoid manual assignments, so if I add fields to `Person` in the future, I don't run the risk to forget to add them to the query.

Comment: Pity but no easy way.